# Magento 2 : Manually delete a design config from mysql

Tags: magento2, database, theme, custom-theme, uninstall

What tables would I remove rows from if I needed to manually remove design configuration rows from the `content > design > configuration` page in the Magento 2.2.3 admin panel

We had themes manually removed from the themes table in the database which of course is not the magento way so now I just need to get back on track and fix this so wanted to figure out how to fully remove the entries in the design configuration page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your `theme` table and delete the entry for your created theme, remember the id of the theme from here.

Then go to your `core_config_data` table and search for theme and you will get path records like `design/theme/theme_id` replace your default theme id in it.

Do remember to flush cache using;

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**EDIT :**

The final issue was with indexers, so don't forget to reindex your indexes to update your design configuration grid using following command ;

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Thanks so in my core_config_data table i have only 2 rows which are correct and in my content > themes admin page it looks all correct. however in my content > themes > configuration page i have a bunch of rows and none list a store or store view and when i click edit on any of them none of the edit links work ecept for the one row that has main website store listed . So trying to fix that issue

Comment: Have you deleted entries from theme table?

Comment: yes all but the there are just two rows in that table but the admin page shows 5 even though I cleared cache in magento and on my browser

Comment: Seems like indexer issue, reindex  all  indexes using php bin/magento indexer:reindex